# El paquete «oracle-java8-set-default» no tiene un candidato para la instalación

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

Intento instalar jdk pero me manda este error

```
introducir el código aquí sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete oracle-java8-set-default no está disponible, pero algún
otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo         
se encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente
Sin embargo, los siguientes paquetes lo reemplazan:
oracle-java12-set-default oracle-java11-set-default-local

E: El paquete «oracle-java8-set-default» no tiene un candidato para la 
instalación
```

También intenté con el siguiente y me da el mismo error

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Llevo atorado en este tema, no sé que pueda hacer, o me pueden ayudar a instalarlo de una manera gráfica? osea sin líneas de comandos

Comment: que versión de Ubuntu posees?

Comment: `Sin embargo, los siguientes paquetes lo reemplazan: oracle-java12-set-default oracle-java11-set-default-local` ¿Has instentado isntalar este paquete?

Comment: Introducir el código aquí es parte del mensaje que obtienes en consola?

Comment: Adiciono el repositorio de webupd8, esos paquetes se encuentran en este repositorio. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el repo *webupd8team* lo han descontinuado desde hace ya tiempo; tuve el mismo inconveniente en Mint 19.1 queriendo instalar la JDK 1.8.0_31, la solucion que encontré es netamente manual:

Lo primero es descargar la JDK desde el sitio web de [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)

Despues, desde terminal (***los comandos varian en la version de JDK!***):

1. Descomprimir al directorio `/usr/lib/jvm`:

`sudo tar -zxf ~/Descargas/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm`

2. Actualizar el comando `java`:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java 100`

3. Actualizar el comando `javac`:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/javac 100`

4. Establecer la JDK de Oracle como default:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java` y selecciona la opcion correspondiente a la JDK 8:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias crack! Me ayudaste demasiado ;)